# Using Pug and expressjs routing, CSS wont display and image wont load, but the data is there

Tags: node.js, express, pug

This happens only when I use route.

**./routes/users.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const dbQuery = require('../controllers/db_query');

router.get('/', async function(req, res) {
  console.log('ROUTE - /');
  const result = await dbQuery.getUsers();
  res.render('users', {
    data: result
  });
});

router.get('/:id', async function(req, res) {
  console.log('ROUTE - /id');
  const result = await dbQuery.getUser(req.params.id);
  console.log('result', result);
  res.render('user', {
    data: result
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**./App.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**./routes/users.js**

```
const router = express.Router();
const dbQuery = require('../controllers/db_query');

router.get('/', async function(req, res) {
  console.log('ROUTE - /');
  const result = await dbQuery.getUsers();
  res.render('users', {
    data: result
  });
});

router.get('/:id', async function(req, res) {
  console.log('ROUTE - /id');
  const result = await dbQuery.getUser(req.params.id);
  console.log('result', result);
  res.render('user', {
    data: result
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**./views/users.pug**

```
extends layout

block content
  // Navigation
  nav#mainNav.navbar.navbar-expand-lg.navbar-light.fixed-top
    .container
      a.navbar-brand.js-scroll-trigger(href='/') Node.js Excersise
      button.navbar-toggler.navbar-toggler-right(type='button' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#navbarResponsive' aria-controls='navbarResponsive' aria-expanded='false' aria-label='Toggle navigation')
        | Menu
        i.fas.fa-bars
  // Masthead
  header.masthead
    .container.d-flex.h-100.align-items-center
      .mx-auto.text-center
        h1.mx-auto.my-0.text-uppercase Users List
        h2.text-white-50.mx-auto.mt-2.mb-5 This is where you can find all the users.
  // Projects
  section#projects.projects-section.bg-light
    .container
        .col-md-10.col-lg-8.mx-auto.text-center
          ul
          each user in data
            div(class='profile-tile')
              img(class='img-rounded' src='images/profile/' + user.Uid + '.jpg' alt= user.Uid + ' image')
              br
              a(class='profile-name' href='/users/' + user.Uid)= user.Uname
              li(style='list-style-type:none')= user.Uemail
  // Contact
  section.contact-section.bg-black
    .container
      .col-md-10.col-lg-8.mx-auto.text-center
          button.btn.btn-primary.mx-auto(onclick="window.location.href='/'") Back
      .social.d-flex.justify-content-center
        a.mx-2(href='#!')
          i.fab.fa-twitter
        a.mx-2(href='#!')
          i.fab.fa-facebook-f
        a.mx-2(href='#!')
          i.fab.fa-github
  // Footer
  footer.footer.bg-black.small.text-center.text-white-50
    .container Copyright &copy; : node.js.exercise 2020
  // Bootstrap core JS
  script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js')
  script(src='javascript/bootstrap.bundle.min.js')
  // Third party plugin JS
  script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js')
  // Core theme JS
  script(src='javascripts/scripts.js')
```

Below is my problem.
I tried to display the data I got from db and pass by route to render. (**see h1 and img**)
I have the result as expected, BUT the image(img) is not displaying and the CSS of the page.

by the way the code below is same with the ./views/users.pug, I did just display the data in simpler way.

**./views/user.pug**

```
extends layout
block content
  nav#mainNav.navbar.navbar-expand-lg.navbar-light.fixed-top
    .container
      a.navbar-brand.js-scroll-trigger(href='/') Node.js Excersise
      button.navbar-toggler.navbar-toggler-right(type='button' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#navbarResponsive' aria-controls='navbarResponsive' aria-expanded='false' aria-label='Toggle navigation')
        | Menu
        i.fas.fa-bars
  // Masthead
  header.masthead
    .container.d-flex.h-100.align-items-center
      .mx-auto.text-center
        h1.mx-auto.my-0.text-uppercase Users List
        h2.text-white-50.mx-auto.mt-2.mb-5 This is where you can find all the users.
  // Projects
  section#projects.projects-section.bg-light
    .container
        .col-md-10.col-lg-8.mx-auto.text-center
          div(class='profile-tile')
            img(class='img-rounded' src='images/profile/' + data[0].Uid + '.jpg' alt='image')
            h1= data[0].Uid
            h1= data[0].Uname
            h1= data[0].Uemail
  // Contact
  section.contact-section.bg-black
    .container
      .col-md-10.col-lg-8.mx-auto.text-center
          button.btn.btn-primary.mx-auto(onclick="window.location.href='/'") Back
      .social.d-flex.justify-content-center
        a.mx-2(href='#!')
          i.fab.fa-twitter
        a.mx-2(href='#!')
          i.fab.fa-facebook-f
        a.mx-2(href='#!')
          i.fab.fa-github
  // Footer
  footer.footer.bg-black.small.text-center.text-white-50
    .container Copyright &copy; : node.js.exercise 2020
  // Bootstrap core JS
  script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js')
  script(src='javascript/bootstrap.bundle.min.js')
  // Third party plugin JS
  script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js')
  // Core theme JS
  script(src='javascripts/scripts.js')
```

**./views/layout.js**

```
head
  meta(charset='utf-8')
  meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no')
  meta(name='description' content='')
  meta(name='author' content='')
  title Node.js
  link(rel='icon' type='image/x-icon' href='/images/favicon.ico')
  // Font Awesome icons (free version)
  script(src='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/js/all.js' crossorigin='anonymous')
  // Google fonts
  link(href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round' rel='stylesheet')
  link(href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i' rel='stylesheet')
  // Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)
  link(href='stylesheets/styles.css' rel='stylesheet')
body
  block content
```

I'm trying to figure out why is it not rendering properly when i go to:
**localhost/users/1**

lastly, I notice that when i go to the route
**localhost/users**
i got the expected result. BUT if I place a **'/'** in the end
**localhost/users/**
I'll will have the problem above. No CSS and it's not reading my static defined in app for my images: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

I'm 2 weeks in learning node.js, I'm trying to learn PUG with it now.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Yes, this could answer this problem, but I'm not able to see this during my research. Thank you for this.

Comment: That's the default comment added when someone flags a question as a duplicate.   This question has been asked and answered before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manage to get the answers for this from my colleague(Thanks to Kevin).

The cause of the issue is, I did not place a '`/`' in from of my `link(href='stylesheets/styles.css' rel='stylesheet')` at **./views/layout.pug**. This cause the browser to assume the path is relative to the document.

**note:** *This can be checked in the browser's network debugging tab.*

When I'm in **localhost:port/users**, the relative path would be okay since the current URL doesn't have '/'. so the stylesheet would work in URLs

localhost:port/users

localhost:port/edit

and so on...

stylesheet's relative path would be:
localhost:port/stylesheets/styles.css (which is correct)

**BUT** when this encounters a '`/`' in the path. the relative path will change base on its current location's/URL's path.

In that case.

e.g

localhost:port/users/

localhost:port/users/1

localhost:port/edit/abc

...

Stylesheet would now be relative to these paths above or document path:

`localhost:port/users/stylesheets/styles.css` (which is NOT correct)

**FIX**

If we place '`/`' at start, the browser will look for that page relative to the root of the website (referred to as an absolute URL).

I also got ideas from this issue:
https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2662